# Regex to split string on double quotes keep only content between quotes

Tags: java, regex, string, split

sorry for the inaccurate Title, but i didn't know how to put it.

If my string would look like this:

```
1+"."+2+"abc"+3+","+12+"."
```

and I would like to get an array containing only the content between the "quotes"

```
.
abc
,
.
```

I would like to receive the above array.

How can i accomplish that?

**Note: all values are random, only the double quotes are certain.**

Example: string can also look like this:

```
23412+"11"+244+"11"+abc+"11"
result should be:
11
11
11
```

or

```
abc+"abc"+abcd+"abcd"
result should be:
abc
abcd
```

or

```
1+"."+2+"."+"."+"3"
result should be:
.
.
.
```

I hope that you can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Match instead of splitting:

```
"([^\"]+)"
```

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/xD6tM4/1)

Comment: +1 Negation pattern is definitely better than using lazy pattern `.*?`

Comment: @anubhava In terms of performance yes (less backtracking), in terms of readability it is matter of style (I find `".*?"` easier to read than `"[^"]*"`). Anyway this is correct regex. +1

Comment: When i use this regex in Java String Split it returns an array of quotes instead of the content between the quotes. Which is strange because in your RegEx Demo it should indeed work.

Comment: @stackr: Use this regex for matching the text not for splitting.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "23412+\"11\"+244+\"11\"+abc+\"11\"\"abcd\"pqrs";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\""); \\ lazy quantifier
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
11
11
11
abcd
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you want regex, but if you can also do it without regex:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String yourString = "23412+\"11\"+244+\"11\"+abc+\"11\"";
        String result = "";
        String[] splitted = yourString.split("\"");
        if (splitted.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i < splitted.length; i += 2) {
                result += splitted[i] + System.lineSeparator();
            }
            result = result.trim();
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

You can use `StringBuilder` for long strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is very simple to write a method that does that and use it as a utility in your program... here's an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = "23412+\"11\"+244+\"11\"+abc+\"11\"\"abcd\"pqrs";
        int i=0;
        ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (i<str.length())
        {
            if(str.charAt(i) == '\"')
            {
                int temp = i;
                do
                {
                    i++;
                }
                while (str.charAt(i) != '\"');

                strList.add(str.substring(temp+1, i));
            }
            i++;
        }
        for(int j=0; j<strList.size(); j++)
        {
            System.out.println(strList.get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

you can change it to return the ArrayList instead of printing it and then you have the perfect utility to do the job